# Load view, then present view

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to load my view then transition to it using a custom segue. The problem is that it's lagging quite a bit, and I can't seem to find the source other than the view being presented is loading during the segue.

```
- (IBAction)continueButtonClicked:(id)sender{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
IntroViewController *imageLoader = (IntroViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"imageLoader"];
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    // present
    [self customSegue:imageLoader];

    // dismiss
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


   });

}
```

I've gone to the extent of incorporating grand central dispatch, but I see no difference. I have little to no experience with GCD either. I have the same segue going to another view and it loads without lag just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can only present UI on the main thread and you are trying to do on a background thread. Try this:

```
- (IBAction)continueButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        IntroViewController *imageLoader = (IntroViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"imageLoader"];

        // present
        [self customSegue:imageLoader];
   });
}
```

I've removed the `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` line because dismissing the presenting view controller will result in the presented view controller not being able to unwind the segue.

Comment: Still does the same thing. Do I need to implement any method like ViewWillAppear or anything in the next view controller to be displayed?